# Linking against OpenCV 2.3.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, linker

i'm new to OpenCV, and i got a problem with linkage.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10,  OpenCV 2.3.1 was installed according to [this](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/.) guide:

I'm building many small applications with it, and it looks fine.
Usually, i'm building with `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`.

Now, i'm trying to build some framework that someone else wrote, it compiles without any problems, but i can't link it: there is a long list of "unresolved reference to..." (thousands of them). all symbols related to opencv_core are not found.

I tried to recompile OpenCV without precompiled header support, didn't help. of course. :(

the test_opencv_core application is running fine, but opencv_rand failed. I think it says that opencv_core is correct, in general, but it still doesn't work when I need it...

Can you please try to give me some hint? I'm lost there.

Thank you in advance,
David

**Update:
Solved.**

gcc 4.6.1 require that the libs and sources will apear in the command line before pathes to shared libs. why? don't know. just spent 24 hours for this stupid mistake :(

**Update:
Understandable.** 
from the ld man page:

> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
>   is specified on the command line.  If the archive defines a symbol
>   which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
>   on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
>   from the archive.  However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
>   later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>   archive again.
>
> See the -( option for a way to force the linker to search archives
>   multiple times.

That's it.

Comment: If the other framework is supplied as a library that you link to, then you might have to link to OpenCV yourself too.

Comment: Thanks. This framework is used as object files, not as a shared library. I just trying to compile a sample application that uses these objects, and the linking is not working.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer (instead of a question edit), and accept it. That way others know it is answered in the future.

Answer (score 1):

gcc 4.6.1 require that the libs and sources will appear in the command line before paths to shared libs. I don't know why.

**Update:
Understandable.** 
from the ld man page:

> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
>   is specified on the command line.  If the archive defines a symbol
>   which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
>   on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
>   from the archive.  However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
>   later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>   archive again.
>
> See the -( option for a way to force the linker to search archives
>   multiple times.

That's it.